# Is there a way to to see what dates/times tickets changed Status via the JIRA API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to run queries against the JIRA API and get results in which I can see the dates and times that each issue went through a status change.

E.g.: Run a query to grab all issues with a certain assignee and see, along with the rest of the information, timestamps for when each issue changed from "Open" to "Resolved".

Is this possible?

EDIT: I have tried expanding the changelog, but while that tells me what status changes a ticket went through (e.g., that the particular ticket transitioned from "Open" to "Resolved" and then from "Resolved" to "Closed"), it doesn't tell me WHEN these transitions occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that each of the transition objects showing the status changes have a "created" field that contains the time and date the transition occurred, which I feel is a bit of a misnomer, but there it is.  An example object inside the "histories" array in the expanded changelog object:

```
{ "author" : { "active" : true,
  "avatarUrls" : { "16x16" : "https://company.jira.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10072",
      "24x24" : "https://company.jira.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10072",
      "32x32" : "https://company.jira.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10072",
      "48x48" : "https://company.jira.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10072"
    },
  "displayName" : "First Last",
  "emailAddress" : "first.last@company.com",
  "name" : "first.last",
  "self" : "https://company.jira.com/rest/api/2/user?username=first.last"
},
"created" : "2013-04-17T16:21:13.540-0400",
"id" : "24451",
"items" : [ { "field" : "status",
    "fieldtype" : "jira",
    "from" : "5",
    "fromString" : "Resolved",
    "to" : "6",
    "toString" : "Closed"
  },
  { "field" : "assignee",
    "fieldtype" : "jira",
    "from" : "old.assignee",
    "fromString" : "Old Assignee",
    "to" : "first.last",
    "toString" : "First Last"
  }
]
}
```